# selenium TimeoutException: Message: python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, request-timed-out

I have the following code, and trying to connect to itunesconnect using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('appleId'))
```

But i was getting `*** TimeoutException: Message:` as below

```
*** TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmp27vpUf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmp27vpUf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmp27vpUf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmp27vpUf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmp27vpUf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Any idea of what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is inside `iframe`, you need to switch to it first

```
driver.switch_to_frame('authFrame') # by frame id, can also be name or WebElement
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('appleId'))
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: @shivakrishna Great :)

Comment: Any ideas with this ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126385/python-selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-staleelementreferenceexception-error

Comment: @shivakrishna I answered to you in the question.