# python selenium selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have the below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa")
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('appleId'))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('pwd'))

username.send_keys("xxxxxxxxxx.com")
password.send_keys("xxxxxxxx")

password.submit()
```

But i got the below error

```
password.submit()
File "/Users/.virtualenvs/itunes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 84, in submit
    self._execute(Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/itunes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/itunes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/.virtualenvs/itunes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9454)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmpR5A61x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9039)
    at WebElement.submitElement (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmpR5A61x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12156)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmpR5A61x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/tmpR5A61x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:625)
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM is rendered when you type into the password field. You need to relocate it

```
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_class_name('dots')) # class dots is added in the rendering
password.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that when you perform any operation over an element some of it's attribute such as the class, value etc. changes and you can't access it further.

Easiest way to tackle this is identify this element again and use it, example :

```
pass = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('pwd'))
pass.submit();
```

Example:
Go to the apple.com log In page, when you inspect the password field. you'll find that it's class changes from `password` to `password focused` when you click on the field and to `password focused edited` when you type over it.